# MIssing Novacode namespace

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, novacode-docx

I just started in my position (3 weeks), and this is my first developer job. I had 8 days with the previous developer before he left, I am now the only developer here (yay me, talk about sink or swim).  I have a program that is getting a missing namespace message for Novacode and DocX (which I believe is part of Novacode)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Novacode;
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
```

The program compiled fine two weeks ago. However, last week they upgraded everything from VS2010 to VS2017.  Would this be causing the missing Namespace?  How do I, where do I get Novacode(which I believe is an add-on)?

Patience with the new guy, trying to learn my job and learn Stackoverflow.

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocX/ may be of some help to you.

Comment: If you have the installation set of the Novacode, try installing it again. Otherwise, search your hard disk for a dll with that name and see if you can add the assembly to the project manually (you need to add it to the References)

Comment: [Not an answer because] I _guess_ that the new install uses different paths than the old one, so it doesn't have the necessary includes and DLLs. You need to install the Novacode set over the new VS2017 setup.

Comment: @Orangesandlemons does this replace the Novacode?  When I search the nugget packages I find DocX, but I can't find how to install Novacode in 2017?  Or am I combining two different things?

Comment: DocX is the package name, the namespace is novacode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find all the Novacode project on github too if you want to add DocX as a project to your solution.

It is very usefull if you want to add more functionnality to the Novacode.DocX based library.

It's what i did personnaly

https://github.com/WordDocX/DocX

Hope this help and good luck for your first job

Answer (score 1):

Just change `Using Novacode;` to `using Xceed.Document.NET;`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding the dll and adding it manually: PER REPSONSE but I can't figure out to mark you response as my answer.

If you have the installation set of the Novacode, try installing it again. Otherwise, search your hard disk for a dll with that name and see if you can add the assembly to the project manually (you need to add it to the References) – Sparrow Aug 24 at 14:22